# Как по названию типа в golang определить сам тип из пакета "go/types"?

Tags: golang

Допустим у меня есть следующие строки: "byte", "int64", "[5]uint64".
В пакете go/types определены все возможные используемые в Go типы, как определить тип из go/types из строки правильно?

Правильно - без switch/case и прочего(такое решение очевидное и сразу же пришло мне в голову), то есть очевидно из компилятора, что на уровне языка эти типы где-то мапятся, хотелось бы узнать где.

Пример: str := "int32" -> strType = types.Int32 или из str2:= "[5] int" -> types.Array

Answer (score 0):

***вариант с reflect удалён***

В пакете `go/parser` есть функция [`parser.ParseExpr`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser#ParseExpr), которая по строчке строит дерево синтаксического разбора. Нужно пройтись по его узлам и собрать тип.

Что-то вроде такого: https://go.dev/play/p/YHZEpx_TObc

В этом примере `str2Type` как парсит строчку и вызывает самописный конструктор типов из `ast`.

```
func str2Type(s string) (types.Type, error) {
    tree, err := parser.ParseExpr(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return mkType(tree)
}

func mkType(node ast.Node) (types.Type, error) {
    switch v := node.(type) {
    case *ast.Ident:
        return mkBasicType(v.Name)
    case *ast.ArrayType:
        return mkArrayType(v.Elt, v.Len)
    case *ast.MapType:
        return mkMapType(v.Key, v.Value)
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown node type: %v", reflect.TypeOf(node))
    }
}

func mkMapType(key ast.Node, value ast.Node) (types.Type, error) {
    typeKey, err := mkType(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    typeVal, err := mkType(value)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return types.NewMap(typeKey, typeVal), nil
}

func mkArrayType(typeNode ast.Node, lenNode ast.Node) (types.Type, error) {
    t, err := mkType(typeNode)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if lenNode == nil {
        return types.NewSlice(t), nil
    }

    literal, ok := lenNode.(*ast.BasicLit)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("not a literal:%v,%v", lenNode.Pos(), lenNode.End())
    }
    length, err := strconv.Atoi(literal.Value)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return types.NewArray(t, int64(length)), nil
}

var basicTypes = map[string]types.Type{
    "int":        types.Typ[types.Int],
    "int8":       types.Typ[types.Int8],
    "int16":      types.Typ[types.Int16],
    "int32":      types.Typ[types.Int32],
    "int64":      types.Typ[types.Int64],
    "uint":       types.Typ[types.Uint],
    "uint8":      types.Typ[types.Uint8],
    "uint16":     types.Typ[types.Uint16],
    "uint32":     types.Typ[types.Uint32],
    "uint64":     types.Typ[types.Uint64],
    "bool":       types.Typ[types.Bool],
    "uintptr":    types.Typ[types.Uintptr],
    "float32":    types.Typ[types.Float32],
    "float64":    types.Typ[types.Float64],
    "complex64":  types.Typ[types.Complex64],
    "complex128": types.Typ[types.Complex128],
    "string":     types.Typ[types.String],
    "byte":       types.Typ[types.Uint8],
    "rune":       types.Typ[types.Int32],
}

func mkBasicType(name string) (types.Type, error) {
    t, ok := basicTypes[name]
    if ok {
        return t, nil
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("not a basic type: %s", name)
    }
}
```

Comment: в рефлекте разве есть такие конструкции? он хорошо читает теги, матчит на деревьях uptr, но вот со строками не слышал и не пробовал, более того конкретики в вашем ответе не увидел. я привел четкие примеры в которых явно показывается что описанное вами не является решением моего вопроса. мне нужен некоторый след чтобы найти лексер по которому go получает тип из строки(из кода). я пишу что-то типо интерпретатора. некоторая похожая функциональность есть в ast https://go.dev/pkg/go/ast/?m=all,old#example_Inspect, но там работа идет только с файлами.

Comment: @SeeNax да, действительно я не про то написал. Вам нужна функция `parser.ParseExpr`, которая по строчке строит AST. Но дальше всё равно придётся пользоваться `select` или приведением типа, чтобы  собирать из дерева конкретный объект `go/types.Type`.